# Visual Studio Wont Let Me Step Throughout A Function With Break Points

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have the following function, and I added two break points on it. I am trying to debug it and step throughout, but the buttons on top are grayed out.

```
void Test::testerFunction1()
{
    const char* Test = "AAAAA";
    HGLOBAL allocatedSpace;
    char* clipboardBuffer;

    if (!OpenClipboard(nullptr))
        return;

    EmptyClipboard();

    //Allocate space on the heap
    allocatedSpace = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, strlen(Test));

    clipboardBuffer = static_cast<char*>(GlobalLock(allocatedSpace));
    GlobalUnlock(allocatedSpace);


    strcpy_s(clipboardBuffer, strlen(clipboardBuffer), Test);


    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, allocatedSpace);

    CloseClipboard();
}
```

What is weird is that when I add the break points and start to debug, the buttons on top are grayed out. I can not step throughout the function using f8, all the buttons on top are grayed out. If I do this to another function, the tools are back to normal. I spend hours trying to debug and I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: Dunno what Visual Studio's problem is, but if you're stuck, don't forget that you can always debug the old-fashioned way by temporarily inserting `printf()` calls (or whatever) into the function to see what gets printed out and what doesn't.

Comment: The buttons at the top will be greyed out, until it hits the breakpoints. Are you sure the code is reached? Are the breakpoints showing as red circles which are filled red, or red circles which aren't filled? Are you in debug or Release?

Comment: @ChrisMM Yes I am sure it is reaching the points. The circles are filled red. I am in debug mode.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner This is more complicated so I need the debug tools.

Comment: One trick I've used (which isn't too far from `printf`) is to put a `Dbg(__FILE__, __LINE__, "message goes here\n");` at points in a routine I want to debug.  That calls my own `void Dbg(char const* fn, int ln, char const* msg) { static int count = 0; ++count; if (msg) OutputDebugStringA(msg); }` global routine, and inside my `Dbg` routine I put a breakpoint.

Comment: @Eljay I really appreciate the help, but I need the debug feature. This feature only works on some of my functions not all. I am not sure what causes it to work for some and not for others.

Comment: It is the debug feature.  The key being for you to set a *breakpoint* inside the `Dbg` routine.

Comment: Did you try setting a break point in whoever calls this function? Or even up in main?

Comment: As written, the question does not provide any useful information to help you. It is not clear about which button your are talking as the condition to enable Step button is not the same as the one to toggle a breakpoint for example. Are you sure that your are compiling a DEBUG version as debugging RELEASE code is harder and there is not a 1 to 1 relation between line of code written and executed code.

Comment: Problem has been solved. The issue was that the compiler for some reason thought the code was not reachable. I fixed that it it solved the issue. Therefore, @ChrisMM is right. It would now reach the code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)